# how can I get a clear x-axis in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try to read-in a file by pandas like this:

```
df=read_csv('C:\Python27\mm.txt',skiprows=7,index_col=[0,1],names=['Date','Time','temp'])
```

then I can get below DataFrame:

```
Date        Time     celsius    
2012-04-12 16:13:09  20.6
2012-04-13 00:13:09  20.6
...
....
```

when I plot the DataFrame,the X-axis becomes so messy,crowded with time like this"2012-04-12 16:13:09". How can the X-axis just show the year and month?

plotting code just like this "df.plot()"

PS：my pandas version is 0.7.3,for some reasons I can't upgrade it.

Comment: you should post your plotting code

Comment: If you include the output of `df.to_dict()` then we can more easily test this ourselves. :)

Comment: 0.7.3 doesn't have real good time series capabilities (>= 0.8 is required and it would be easy with using `parse_dates=True`). I would suggest to upgrade. I you cannot, maybe this is another question.

Comment: I have upgraded the pandas to 0.9.0.and add this line 'parse_dates=True' into 'read_csv' function.but it still messy.why?

Answer (score 0):

method:

```
def parse(datet):
dt=datetime.strptime(datet[0:10],'%Y-%m-%d')
delta=timedelta(hours=int(datet[11:13]),minutes=int(datet[14:17]))
return dt+delta

df=read_csv('c:/py/mimi',skiprows=7,parse_date={'datet':[0,1]},index_col='datet',date_parser=parse)
```